# Custom field linking problem!

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a post in wordpress with custom field. I've added this custom field with a plugin called Custom Field Suite. 
The custom field is a hyperlink. I've named it tracking_url. For example it can be gooogle.com or whatever...

I want to add a button in funcions.php to be displayed on the homepage, THAT links to the tracking_url,..

I am doing this but my knowledge of Php is limited. I am a front end developer.

```
!-- Claim Your Bonus Button -->
    <p class="readmore">
    <a class="more-link claim-bonus" href="<?php $meta_value = get_post_meta($postID->ID, 'tracking_url', true ); ?>" rel="nofollow" title="">Claim Bonus &raquo; </a>
     </p>
```

Can you help me with the php part. I want to link the button to tracking_url
Thanks! :)

Comment: You might be better off is not advanced custom fields. Then you can use the_field('tracking_url');

Comment: Premature submit. Sorry. But yeah. Fields are also a lot easier to setup to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What you're meant to be doing is `echo`ing the `$meta_value`, not assigning it to a variable.

Also don't forget to escape the value :)

```
<!-- Claim Your Bonus Button -->
<p class="readmore">
    <a class="more-link claim-bonus" href="<?php echo( esc_url( get_post_meta( $postID->ID, 'tracking_url', true ) ) ); ?>" rel="nofollow" title="">Claim Bonus &raquo; </a>
</p>
```